# page template for attachement page?

Tags: php, functions, attachments, page-template

hey guys,
I couldn't find anything on the web. Is it possible to have custom template for the image attachement page. I wonder if it is possible to add a navigation to the image attachement page so people can easily navigate through a gallery.

Maybe it's even possible to add comments to each image?

edit: Moreover is it also possible to query if I'm currently on an attachement page? E.g. for breadcrumbs I want to insert something like "home > back to post > current_image.jpg"

edit/update:

```
function breadcrumbs() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo "<a href='" . get_bloginfo('home') . "' title='Home'>Home</a> &rang; ";
        if (is_category()) {
            $category = get_the_category(); 
            echo $category[0]->cat_name;
        } else if (is_single()) {
            the_category('title_li=');
            echo " &rang; ";
            the_title();
        } else if (is_page()) {
            $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
            // echo ancestors
            foreach($ancestors as $id) {
                echo "<a href='" . get_permalink( $id ) . "' title='" . get_the_title( $id ) . "'>" . get_the_title( $id ) . "</a> &rang; ";
            }
        } else if (is_tag()) {
            global $wp_query;
            $tag = get_term( $wp_query->queried_object_id, 'post_tag');
            echo "Tag &rang; " . $tag->name;
        } else if (is_search()) {
            echo " Searchresults &rang; " . get_search_query();
        } else if (is_404()) {
            echo "Not found";
        //} else if ( is_attachment() ) {
        } else if ($post->post_type == 'attachment') {
            //echo "<a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a>";
            echo "doesn't work?";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress supports several types of attachment templates. The function `get_attachment_template` in `wp-includes/theme.php` provides this support; it is called in `wp-includes/template-redirect.php`. If your theme includes `attachment.php` all of your attachments will be rendered with that template. If your theme also includes `image.php` then all of your images will use that template as long as they have a post_mime_type of `image/*`.

It is certainly possible to add gallery navigation. See `wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop-attachment.php` which uses functions `previous_image_link` and `next_image_link`.

Twentyten's attachment template does call `comments_template` so you can collect comments on each photo. You just have to make sure your post links to the attachment pages and not directly to the images.

You can call `is_attachment` to determine whether the queried object is an attachment.

Comment: thank you, I updated my post. I'm using the twenty ten templates now an will try to adapt them to my needs. Anyway, only thing I can't find out is how to make my breadcrumbs work so they show `home > current post title as link > current image`

Answer (score 6):

Short answer - Yes.

Attachments are served by template files based on their mime-type, So if your attachment is an image/jpg, for example, WordPress will first look for a template file named image.php, then jpg.php, and then finally attachment.php, before falling back on another template file (single.php or index.php). There's a good chart showing the template hierarchy on the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

This only works if you're accessing the attachment through WP's rewrite structure (ie. when you insert the image, choosing the "link to post" rather than "link to file" option. The url should look something like domain.com/post-name/attachment-name ... Accessing the file URL directly bypasses WordPress temple system.

And, if you want to check if you're on an attachment page, you can always check the post type, ie.

```
if ($post->post_type == 'attachment') {
```

Of course, within an attachment.php template, there's no readon to bother checking that - you already know you're on an attachment page.

Comment: Creating gallery navigation links (using thumbnails) isn't difficult. Take a look at `attachment-loop.php` in TwentyTen. Also, any reason not to use `is_attachment()`, rather than `$post->post_type == 'attachment'`?

Comment: @Chip and @Andy - No, no reason at all. I've never had to use the `is_attachment()` conditional, but you're right, thats a better approach. It should be available from much earlier, whereas `$post->post_type` is only available in the Loop.